# Does the BackEnd of DatasetGraphInMemory outperform TripleStoreMem outside of transaction in Jena

Tags: jena

I'm simply curious to know, if in a context where, transaction are not necessary, neither quads, but lot of sparql query on the model, would the TripleTable outperform the TripleStoreMem (taking into account whatever wraps them)

So instead of

```
ModelFactory.createDefaultModel()
```

how about defaulting to

```
DatasetFactory.createTxnMem().getDefaultModel
```

In the second case i would keep the dataset of course, but get its default model to read into it, and query the dataset.

Would running query on the second model (i.e. its dataset) outpeform running query on the first (i.e. the dataset it will wrap in automatically anyway).

The bottom line is both are backed by different mechanism, and i wonder if that would matter for that specific use case, where the goal is simply to run query on a model after readying it.

A Stretch of the question is, what is the most performant backend (model/graph) to use to do this kind of operation, where there is no need for transaction or persistence but just speed of query.

## EDIT1

The reason i specify inside of transaction is because I follow 2 documentations.

The Javadoc of

```
public static DatasetGraph createTxnMem() { return new DatasetGraphInMemory(); }
```

in DatasetGraphFactory, says

> It provides "autocommit" if operations are performed outside a transaction but with a performance impact (the implementation adds a begin/commit around each add or delete so overheads can accumulate).

However, given that DatasetGraphInMemory is not documented in the official doc other than the java, the closest i could find was the tutorial on TDB.
It says:

> TDB supports the general Jena API for transactions on RDF datasets (introduced in Jena 2.7.0, ARQ 2.9.0).

> A TDB-backed dataset can be used non-transactionally but once used in a transaction, it must be used transactionally after that.

Hence I figured, that might work for DatasetGraphInMemory as they basically have the same ancestor. TDB being specialized for persistence.

However it seems that it can't be used non-transactionally, as the auto-commit would kick in anyway.

Hence do i need to manage the transaction manually, and is it worth it, if i only wants speed, Will I actually gain ?

Answer (score 1):

It will be usage dependent.

TIM (TIM = "Transactions In Memory" = DatasetGraphInMemory) uses persistent datastructures (in the functional programming sense of "persistent"). The implementation is provided by Dexx collections.

It generates more short-term objects so has a GC effect.

In cases of large number of very small updates, TIM may be slower. Whether that is observable given the rest of the application is situation dependent.